# Separate password field to password first and password second on twig

Tags: symfony, passwords, twig, formbuilder

I have on my form builder a password with type : RepeatedType

```
 -> add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                     'required' => true,
                     'type' => PasswordType::class,
                     'first_options' => array('label' => 'label.password'),
                     'second_options' => array('label' => 'label.confirm_password'),
                 ))
```

on the twig part I want to display them in the same row like the folloing picture:

[image]

but I dont know how to separate them on the twig:

I have tried:

```
{{ form_row(form.password, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

but they look like:

[image]

**Update** this how I did it I hope it will hepl others:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">{{ form_row(form.password.second) }}</div>


                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you twig file, refer to them as :

```
{{ form_row(form.password.first, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
{{ form_row(form.password.second, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

More details on that : 
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-security/user-registration-form

Also if you use bootstrap, you can use form-row and col classes maybe something like :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      {{ form_row(form.password.first, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      {{ form_row(form.password.second, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```